# GET from IE11 to google doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-11, spdy, ieaddon

I'm developing an extension for IE11 and as part of it I'm using an xhr (GET) to Google's settings page. 
The code runs on the background page.

These are the details that I'm passing -

```
var details = {
            url: "https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1&hl=en&rt=j", 
            method: 'GET',
            async: true,
            contentType: 'text'
        }
```

And here's the call -

```
kango.xhr.send(details, function(data) { 
// Yada yada yada
});
```

It works great on Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Chromium and it even worked on IE11 up until today.

The response I'm getting is

```
{"response":"","status":"0","abort":{}}
```

Cache is not the problem.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Works in every major browser, but not in IE? That's absurd... Try setting your payload to the empty string. It's a long shot, but worth a try :)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a security update behind this:

> This issue occurs if the Internet connection is established through certain proxy servers when the SPDY/3 protocol is enabled in Internet Explorer.
>
> To resolve this issue, install the most recent cumulative security update for Internet Explorer. To do this, go to Microsoft Update.
>
> Note This update was first included in security update 2925418.

**References**

- [An update is available that disables Enhanced Protected Mode by default in Internet Explorer 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2907803)
- [Sites that support SPDY do not load first time when IE is configured to use a proxy server and SPDY is enabled](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/813993/ie11-sites-that-support-spdy-do-not-load-first-time-when-ie-is-configured-to-use-a-proxy-server-and-spdy-is-enabled)
- ["This page can't be displayed" error when you browse a Google webpage in Internet Explorer 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2928510)
- [Internet Explorer 11 - New Technical Features](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/dn269977.aspx)
- [A Developer's Survival Guide to IE Protected Mode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18866/A-Developer-s-Survival-Guide-to-IE-Protected-Mode)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but by disabling SPDY/3 on IE11, it should have prevented the problem?
Cause I did it, and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is there a session cookie in the other browsers that is missing in IE11? Look for differences in the network request using the developer tools in each browser and check the [epm](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2907803) settings for IE11.